# Hi,I need to ask the user to enter 3 values until he enters EOF(Ctrl+z).The EOF part isn't working and the user enters 6 values each time and I need 3

Tags: c

```
#define SIZE 7
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int NoOfDoors[SIZE];
int CarManufYear[SIZE];
float CarCost[SIZE];
for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
printf("\nEnter 3 values (Door, year, price):");
scanf("%d%d%f", &NoOfDoors[i], &CarManufYear[i], &CarCost[i]);
if(scanf("%d%d%f", &NoOfDoors[i], &CarManufYear[i], &CarCost[i])==EOF)
{
break;
}
}
printf("End of the code");
return 0;
}
```

// the code is reading 6 values (instead of 3) then print the message again to read. Also, the EOF part is not working properly.

Comment: You're calling `scanf` twice, once above the `if` then once in the `if` itself, so you need to capture the return value of `scanf` to test for `EOF` in your `if`, ie: `int r` `r = scanf(...)` `if (r == EOF)` ... or just test it directly in your `if`

Comment: "The scanf function prototype is: `int scanf(const char *format, ...);` scanf returns EOF if end of file (or an input error) occurs before any values are stored. If any values are stored, it returns the number of items stored; that is, it returns the number of times a value is assigned by one of the scanf argument pointers. " So I think you might have a misconception. Pressing "enter" or "Ctrl+z" won't make `scanf` return `EOF`

Comment: Please reformat your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

Call `scanf()` once per iteration and save the return value.  Then test the return value.

```
for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
  printf("\nEnter 3 values (Door, year, price): ");
  int retval = scanf("%d%d%f", &NoOfDoors[i], &CarManufYear[i], &CarCost[i]);
  if(retval == EOF) {
    break;
  }
  if(retval != 3) {
    Handle_incorrect_input(); // TBD code
    break;
  }
  printf("Door:%d Year:%d Price:%.2f", NoOfDoors[i], CarManufYear[i], CarCost[i]);

}
```